# Do you know a HTML-Snippet Validator?

Tags: html, validation, xhtml

I'm searching for a tool that would allow me to check whether a certain snippet of HTML would be valid in it's proper context.

I'd input something like

```
<dd>
    my definition 
    <div>
        div inside &lt;dd&gt; is allowed
    </div>
</dd>
```

instead of the whole document. A ordinary validator will complain about the missing dl-tag, but most of the times I just want to know whether a certain element is valid inside another one or not.

---

I'll try to explain it more detailed. Consider the following snippet:

```
<form>
    <label>Name: <input /></label>
</form>
```

Would be valid, but to check it I have two options:

1. Validate the whole document: Most of the times this is good enough, but sometimes when I'm working on partial HTML snippets or embedded HTML it's quite some trouble. I'd have to copy the whole thing to a new HTML document and validate that.
2. Just copy the snippet and validate it with the W3C validator and ignore some of the errors.

Basically I'd like to check, whether an element contains only elements it's allowed to contain.

Comment: That snippet is invalid solely and precisely because of the missing `<dl>` tags. It's fine to have a `<div>` within a `<dd>`.

Comment: I am not sure but you can try netbeans IDE, pasting the html snippet in Netbeans editor will highlight errors and warnings in your html snippet.

Comment: For emacs-users: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HtmlCheckFrag checks matching pairs of non-void html-tags. Errors are highlighted. If there are errors in the document that is indicated in the mode-line. `S-Mouse-1` on the indicator in the mode line searches the document for the next error. This also works for HTML-snippets. No check yet for such things whether `<td></td>` is inside `<table></table>` and so on.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can actually use the W3C validator to check a snippet.

Choose the 'Validate by Direct Input' tab and select More Options. In there there is a radio button to 'Validate HTML fragment'. http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options

It will wrap your page in valid html so the errors which you see are only due to your snippet.

Comment: Validate with HTML fragment feature is not active now

Answer (score 0):

W3C does currently (May 2020) have a fragment validator, but it seems to have bitrot (no HTML5, at least). Here's a couple of simple scripts that attach a header and a footer to your fragment, and run the result through a local copy of the [Nu checker](https://validator.github.io/validator/). The fragment can be anything which is valid at the top level of a `<body>` tag - modify the header and footer if you need something else.

`validate1.sh` takes a single filename argument and checks it, while `validate2.sh` cycles through all HTML files in a directory. It has a simple exclusion list mechanism which you'll need to change. You'll need to modify both to point to your copy of `vnu.jar`.

`validate1.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# validate1.sh
#
# Run the nu validator on the HTML fragment in the supplied filename.
# This script adds a header and trailer around the fragment, and supplies
# the result to 'vnu.jar'. You'll need to modify it to correctly locate
# vnu.jar.

if test "$#" -ne 1; then
    echo "Usage: '$0 fname', where 'fname' is the HTML file to be linted"
    exit 1
fi

var="<!doctype html>
     <html lang=\"en\">
     <head>
     <title>foo</title>
     </head>
     <body>
     $(< "$1")
     </body>
     </html>"
echo "Checking '$1'... subtract 6 from any reported line numbers"
echo "$var" | java -jar vnu.jar -
```

`validate2.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# validate2.sh
#
# Run the nu validator on the HTML fragments in the supplied directory.  This
# script adds a header and footer around each fragment in the directory, and
# supplies the result to 'vnu.jar'. You'll need to modify it to correctly
# locate vnu.jar.

if test "$#" -ne 1; then
    echo "Usage: '$0 fname', where 'fname' is the HTML directory to be linted"
    exit 1
fi

for filename in $1/*.html; do
    case $filename in
        # simple exclusion list example:
        "$1/root.html" | "$1/sitedown.html")
            echo "Skipping '$filename'"
            continue
            ;;
        *)
            ;;
    esac

    var="<!doctype html>
         <html lang=\"en\">
         <head>
         <title>foo</title>
         </head>
         <body>
         $(< "$filename")
         </body>
         </html>"
    echo "Checking '$filename'... subtract 6 from any reported line numbers"
    echo "$var" | java -jar vnu.jar -
done
```